# what's the expanded expression of $\lVert\vec a+\vec b\rVert^3$

Tags: linear-algebra, vectors

We know that $$\lVert\vec a+\vec b\rVert^2=\lVert \vec a\rVert^2+\lVert \vec b\rVert^2+2\vec a\cdot\vec b$$
so what's the expanded expression of $\lVert\vec a+\vec b\rVert^3$?

Would that be $\lVert \vec a\rVert^3+\lVert \vec b\rVert^3+3\lVert \vec a\rVert^2\lVert \vec b\rVert+3\lVert \vec a\rVert\lVert \vec b\rVert^2$ ?

$\lVert \vec a\rVert$ means the Euclidian norm of the vector $\vec a$

Comment: Do you mean to describe $\left\| a+ b \right\|^3$? how do you multiply two vectors?

Comment: Cubing doesn't make sense for vectors because dot product returns a scalar.

Comment: The types are wacky here. I take it you're overloading ${}^2$ by defining ${\vec{a}}^2 = \vec{a} \cdot \vec{a}$. But if you look at what operations are available, you'll see that overloading ${}^3$ similarly is ... problematic.

Comment: @SiongThyeGoh,yes, sorry, I'll edit it.

Comment: @pjs36, I've already corrected my question.

Comment: @servabat, I've already corrected my question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No. It's not what you wrote. The norm is $$ ||\vec a + \vec b|| =\sqrt{||\vec a||^2+||\vec b||^2 +2\vec a\cdot\vec b}$$ so you have $$ ||\vec a + \vec b||^3 =\left(||\vec a||^2+||\vec b||^2 +2\vec a\cdot\vec b)\right)^{3/2}.$$ There isn't really a way to simplify it further.

Comment: Sorry, it's a mistake. I've already edited it.

Comment: @JohnnyJi it was a more interesting question before. Changed my answer to match it anyway.

Comment: I think the formula $ ||\vec a + \vec b|| =\sqrt{||\vec a||^2+||\vec b||^2 +2\vec a\cdot\vec b}$ is derived from the definition of norm, not the definition itself. So I wonder if I can get a similar formula when the order is 3.

Comment: @JohnnyJi ??? What is "the definition itself"? The norm is what I wrote down. To get its cube you just cube it, giving the second thing I wrote. Unlike the old version of the question, the notation here is pretty much standard. The formula you wrote down is for $(||\vec a|| + ||\vec b||)^3,$ a different quantity since $||\vec a|| + ||\vec b||\ne ||\vec a +\vec b||.$

Comment: Thanks. I got it.

Answer (score 0):

$$\|\vec {a}+\vec {b}\|^3=(\|\vec {a}+\vec {b}\|^2)^\frac 32$$

Comment: But why not make ${\vec{u}}^n$ a vector in the same space as $\vec{u}$ for odd $n$?

Comment: Already edit it.

Answer (score 0):

Nonsense-- $(\vec{a}+\vec{b})^3$ makes no sense (how do you multiply a vector by another?)

Also, $(\vec{a}+\vec{b})^2$ makes no sense.  $(\vec{a}+\vec{b})^2$ is not a synonym for  $(\vec{a}+\vec{b})\cdot (\vec{a}+\vec{b})$.

Comment: Well, $(\vec a + \vec b)$ is commonly a synonym for $(\vec a + \vec b)\cdot (\vec a + \vec b)$. I guess it depends on the country.

Comment: I mean the norm, it's a typo. Already edit it.